# Approving updates for WSUS test group, then approving for all others

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

Setting up a new WSUS server for our environment here.  Best practice seems to be to have a "test group" of machines that get updates approved for them first, then once there seem to be no issues, they are approved for the remaining machines.

I was just testing this out, and there were some updates in the "All Updates" section.  I have two groups in the WSUS server, Trial Workstations and Normal Workstations.

I approved the update for the Trial Workstation group only, and now it is no longer displayed in the "All Updates" section.  How can I go back and approved that update for the remaining workstations?

Comment: There are two drop downs at the top of the panel where your updates are displayed. Is the approval one set to "Unapproved" by any chance? If it is, change that to something else ("Any except declined") and hit refresh and see if they re-appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a filtered view for given group - right click on the **Updates** container and select **New Update View...**. Then Select the **Updates are approved for specific group...** checkbox. Please note that this will not show any inherited updates, so you should select the top most staging computers container in the Edit properties box, if you have any. And finally you give it a name.

You can also add filtering by date, but this is limited to three predefined periods, so not much of a use.

Refer to [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc708436) for more details on using the WSUS console.